# Why is auto_increment "spelled" with an underscore?

Tags: sql

I was wondering why `auto_increment` is "spelled" with an underscore, since `primary key` `not null` and such is not?

Is it because `auto_increment` is some old syntactical leftover or such?

Comment: Interesting - but totally **off-topic** - belongs on [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com)

Comment: might be a little of topic, but it certainly doesn't belong on english. The question is about sql syntax & convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys can be either primary or foreign, columns can be either null(able) or not null.

There isn't really an alternative increment option to auto_ - so it makes more sense to have it as one "word".

Answer (score 0):

I would guess because it it is actually a niladic function (such as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` from the SQL standard). Even if it has no parameters today it could have them in the future e.g. for seed and increment (as per SQL Server's `IDENTITY`).